# Desktop touch screen pinch/pan (zoom) on specific element (iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pan, pinch

We're hosting html content inside an iframe on our web page.
Is it possible to deactivate zooming for the whole page but enable it for a specific element (iframe) on a desktop touch screen, so the user can pinch/pan the html content of the iframe? Right now when we pinch (zoom) the iframe, the whole page will be zoomed. WE tried multiple pinch/pan libraries but they all seem to only work for images